# My c# program for square roots only works when the discriminant is 0 or less than 0, but not when it's greater than 0

Tags: c#, string, parsing, if-statement, square-root

```
private void btnCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double coefficientA;
    double coefficientB;
    double coefficientC;
    double root1;
    double root2;
    double discriminant;

    coefficientA = double.Parse(txtCoeA.Text);
    coefficientB = double.Parse(txtCoeB.Text);
    coefficientC = double.Parse(txtCoeC.Text);

    discriminant = 
            (coefficientB * coefficientB) - 
            (4 * coefficientA * coefficientC);

    txtOutput.Text = "Discriminant = " + discriminant.ToString("N2");

    //-b/2a

    root1 = (-coefficientB + discriminant) / (2 * coefficientA);
    root2 = (-coefficientB - discriminant) / (2 * coefficientA);

    if (discriminant < 0)
    {
            txtOutput.Text += "\r\nEquation has no real roots!";
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0)
    {
        txtOutput.Text += 
            "\r\nEquation has one root: " + root2.ToString("N2");
    }        
    else if (discriminant > 0)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = "Equation has two real roots: " +
            "\r\nroot1: " + 
            (-coefficientB + Math.Sqrt(discriminant) / 
            (2 * coefficientA)) +
            "\r\nroot2: " + (coefficientB - Math.Sqrt(discriminant) / 
            (2 * coefficientA)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Quadratic roots, not square roots.

Comment: Also, should you not be taking the square root of the discriminant?

Comment: Is it not? Math.Sqrt(discriminant) takes care of that doesn't it?

Comment: There is mistakes in parenthesis, roots are `(-coefficientB + Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * coefficientA)` and `(-coefficientB - Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * coefficientA)`

Comment: What is your method trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh my gosh! How dumb of me. Thank you so much! That fixes it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    txtOutput.Text = "Equation has two real roots: " +
        "\r\nroot1: " + 
        (-coefficientB + Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * coefficientA) +
        "\r\nroot2: " +
        (-coefficientB - Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * coefficientA);
```

You were bracketing the formula incorrectly.

Comment: ..and, even after the edit, 'root1 = (-coefficientB + discriminant) / (2 * coefficientA);' etc. has been left in.

Comment: Note also that 'root2' is missing the '-b'.

Comment: @MartinJames - Yes, I noticed that, but he's not using `root1` or `root2` so I just decided to ignore that.

Comment: @MartinJames - Ta. I fixed the `-b`.